# php include is not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to get my config.php file to work but everytime i use it with my login.php it just gives me a white page rather than continuing through my login.php file towards my members.php page. I put my connection info into my login.php script and it works properly listed below is what i been trying to do.

config.php

```
<?php 

$con = mysql_connect("mysql","DBUSER","DBPASS");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("DBNAME", $con);

/* WHAT I ORIGINALLY WANTED TO USE
$localhost = "mysql";
$dbuser = "DBUSER";
$dbpass = "DBPASS";
$dbname = "DBNAME";

$connect = mysql_connect($localhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db("$dbname", $connect); 
*/

?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
// I ALSO USED includes"config.php";
require("config.php");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '$username' AND password =       '$password'");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'];
header("Location: members.php");
exit;
}

header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

I'm new to PHP so don't laugh at my code please thanks for the help!

Comment: white page of death = error but you have error checking off or not displaying.

Comment: Any errors? Check your error logs

Comment: includes should be `include("config.php");` http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Don't use the mysql_* api anymore, it's being deprecated.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On top of your code turn on errors:

```
ini_set("display_errors","On");
```

and make sure you can see your mysql errors:

```
$query = mysql_query(...) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

And one last thing: although `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated, if you use them always escape your data before you use it in your query; you can be victim of [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Ok ill give that a try thanks I'll try those and look into sql injections!

Comment: my two msgs when I add ini_set are:Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /php/config.php:21) in /php/login.php on line 13

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /php/config.php:21) in /andrew/login.php on line 15

Comment: What this means is that you are setting your headers after they are already sent. move the session_start in your config maybe.

Comment: @AndrewL one little trick will be to remove the closing php tag `?>` in your config file. sometimes a space is added and the header is sent.

Comment: It works! I removed the ?> and made sure i used include... instead of includes..and bam works like a charm! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
include "config.php";
```

it should be `include` not `includes`